# Select Count of one table into another

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle11g

I have one *SQL* statement as:

```
SELECT ARTICLES.NEWS_ARTCL_ID, ARTICLES.NEWS_ARTCL_TTL_DES, 
  ARTICLES.NEWS_ARTCL_CNTNT_T, ARTICLES.NEWS_ARTCL_PUB_DT, 
  ARTICLES.NEWS_ARTCL_AUTH_NM, ARTICLES.NEWS_ARTCL_URL, ARTICLES.MEDIA_URL, 
  ARTICLES.ARTCL_SRC_ID, SOURCES.ARTCL_SRC_NM, MEDIA.MEDIA_TYPE_DESCRIP
FROM 
  RSKLMOBILEB2E.NEWS_ARTICLE ARTICLES,
  RSKLMOBILEB2E.MEDIA_TYPE MEDIA, 
  RSKLMOBILEB2E.ARTICLE_SOURCE SOURCES 
WHERE ARTICLES.MEDIA_TYPE_IDENTIF = MEDIA.MEDIA_TYPE_IDENTIF 
 AND ARTICLES.ARTCL_SRC_ID = SOURCES.ARTCL_SRC_ID  
 AND ARTICLES.ARTCL_SRC_ID = 1 
ORDER BY ARTICLES.NEWS_ARTCL_PUB_DT
```

Now I need to combine another *SQL* statement into one which is:

```
SELECT COUNT ( * )
FROM RSKLMOBILEB2E.NEWS_LIKES LIKES, RSKLMOBILEB2E.NEWS_ARTICLE ARTICLES
WHERE LIKES.NEWS_ARTCL_ID = ARTICLES.NEWS_ARTCL_ID
```

Basically I have one table which contains articles and I need to include the user likes which is in another table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `subquery` to add the `likescount` in your first query like this:

```
SELECT ARTICLES.NEWS_ARTCL_ID
    ,ARTICLES.NEWS_ARTCL_TTL_DES
    ,ARTICLES.NEWS_ARTCL_CNTNT_T
    ,ARTICLES.NEWS_ARTCL_PUB_DT
    ,ARTICLES.NEWS_ARTCL_AUTH_NM
    ,ARTICLES.NEWS_ARTCL_URL
    ,ARTICLES.MEDIA_URL
    ,ARTICLES.ARTCL_SRC_ID
    ,SOURCES.ARTCL_SRC_NM
    ,MEDIA.MEDIA_TYPE_DESCRIP
    ,(
        SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM RSKLMOBILEB2E.NEWS_LIKES LIKES
        WHERE LIKES.NEWS_ARTCL_ID = ARTICLES.NEWS_ARTCL_ID
        ) AS LikesCount
FROM RSKLMOBILEB2E.NEWS_ARTICLE ARTICLES
    ,RSKLMOBILEB2E.MEDIA_TYPE MEDIA
    ,RSKLMOBILEB2E.ARTICLE_SOURCE SOURCES
WHERE ARTICLES.MEDIA_TYPE_IDENTIF = MEDIA.MEDIA_TYPE_IDENTIF
    AND ARTICLES.ARTCL_SRC_ID = SOURCES.ARTCL_SRC_ID
    AND ARTICLES.ARTCL_SRC_ID = 1
ORDER BY ARTICLES.NEWS_ARTCL_PUB_DT;
```

Comment: Thank you @FutbolFan this sql warks perfect. :)

Comment: Hi @FutbolFan,
I am trying to select top 10 'liked' articles between dates, I tried the using BETWEEN clause to select between dates but not sure how to select top 10 liked articles. Could you advise?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve but it seems you want to count all the data from 2 tables. You can edit your query to something like this.

```
SELECT COUNT (ARTICLES.*) FROM RSKLMOBILEB2E.NEWS_LIKES LIKES
JOIN RSKLMOBILEB2E.NEWS_ARTICLE ARTICLES 
ON LIKES.NEWS_ARTCL_ID = ARTICLES.NEWS_ARTCL_ID
```

Comment: I have one select query which I mentioned above which gives the list of articles and now along with that I also want to display the count of user likes on those articles.

Comment: I understand now. It seems you wanted to count something so your query should go something the column that needs to be involved, the count function and the GROUP BY clause where all the columns involved in the SELECT statement are declared. To relate the tables, you can use join and pertain the condition on how each table is related to. (eg. ARTICLES.ID = SOURCES.ID) something like that.

Answer (score 0):

I think that solution is in using Analytic Functions. Please have a look on https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/analytic-functions

Please check following query (keep in mind I have no idea about your table structures). Due to left join records might be duplicated, this is why grouping is added.

```
SELECT ARTICLES.NEWS_ARTCL_ID, ARTICLES.NEWS_ARTCL_TTL_DES, 
  ARTICLES.NEWS_ARTCL_CNTNT_T, ARTICLES.NEWS_ARTCL_PUB_DT, 
  ARTICLES.NEWS_ARTCL_AUTH_NM, ARTICLES.NEWS_ARTCL_URL, ARTICLES.MEDIA_URL, 
  ARTICLES.ARTCL_SRC_ID, SOURCES.ARTCL_SRC_NM, MEDIA.MEDIA_TYPE_DESCRIP, 
  count(LIKES.ID) over ( partition by ARTICLES.NEWS_ARTCL_ID ) as num_likes
FROM RSKLMOBILEB2E.NEWS_ARTICLE ARTICLES
join RSKLMOBILEB2E.MEDIA_TYPE MEDIA 
on ARTICLES.MEDIA_TYPE_IDENTIF = MEDIA.MEDIA_TYPE_IDENTIF 
join RSKLMOBILEB2E.ARTICLE_SOURCE SOURCES 
on ARTICLES.ARTCL_SRC_ID = SOURCES.ARTCL_SRC_ID   
LEFT JOIN RSKLMOBILEB2E.NEWS_LIKES LIKES
 ON LIKES.NEWS_ARTCL_ID = ARTICLES.NEWS_ARTCL_ID
 WHERE 
  ARTICLES.ARTCL_SRC_ID = 1 
 group by ARTICLES.NEWS_ARTCL_ID, ARTICLES.NEWS_ARTCL_TTL_DES, 
  ARTICLES.NEWS_ARTCL_CNTNT_T, ARTICLES.NEWS_ARTCL_PUB_DT, 
  ARTICLES.NEWS_ARTCL_AUTH_NM, ARTICLES.NEWS_ARTCL_URL, ARTICLES.MEDIA_URL, 
  ARTICLES.ARTCL_SRC_ID, SOURCES.ARTCL_SRC_NM, MEDIA.MEDIA_TYPE_DESCRIP
ORDER BY ARTICLES.NEWS_ARTCL_PUB_DT
```

I also changed coma-separated list of tables from where condition to joins. I think this is more readable since table join conditions are separated from result filtering in where clause.